# How can this webm file detect my web browser?

Tags: webm

This [video](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/672195516955754499/1002722552986206279/4dff80e50e7d1525.webm) spreading across Discord is very intriguing...

[image]

The same webm file behaves as follows in the following browsers:

| Browser / Player | Message |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome | "Discord detected on Chromium/Electron" |
| Firefox | "Discord detected on Gecko (Firefox)" |
| VLC | "Discord detected on Gecko (Firefox)" |
| Media Player Classic | "Discord detected on Chromium/Electron" |
| Edge | "Discord detected on Chromium/Electron" |
| Safari | Play bar loads but only plays first frame of video. |
| Epiphany | Play bar loads but won't play at all. |
| Edge (Legacy) | Won't load/play |
| IE11 | Won't load/play |
| Windows 10 Movies and TV | Won't load/play |

I'm well aware that the "Discord" part of the message baked-in to the video, but what about the rest?

I had originally suspected that the `.webm` file was somehow switching to a streaming method and using server-side headers to influence the video content, but I tried in a VM in airplane mode and it still worked.

My second thought is that since `.webm`-capable browsers can be split up into two groups: Chromium-based and Gecko-based, that this video has multiple video sources embedded and is taking advantage of a very specific browser incompatibility, like a magic trick that [forces you to select a card](https://www.goodtricks.net/card-forces.html).

Comment: I suspect the file is intentionally malformed. There are two video tracks, one meant for firefox, the other for chrome. VLC doesn't show a length and has problems switching between the tracks.

Comment: To elaborate a bit further and quote @Ouroborus's comment on Discord: ... "The `.webm` file format supports multiple video streams, and it seems like different platforms use a different default demultiplexer.  `vlc 4dff80e50e7d1525.webm --demux mkv` will give you a different result than `vlc 4dff80e50e7d1525.webm --demux avformat`, for example."